# Filtrar informacion en diccionarios python dinamicamente

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

En primer lugar, quiero decir que estoy entendiendo cómo filtrar la información en los diccionarios de Python desde un JSON para luego escribirlos en un archivo JSON. Tomo un flujo de trabajo normal partiendo que no siempre sabemos exactamente a qué debemos iterar. Para ilustrar un ejemplo simple pero de la vida real.

### El flujo de trabajo

- Decodificar JSON
- Tratar y procesar los datos (convertirlos en información)
- Codificar JSON Y escríbirlos en un archivo

### El ejemplo

para esto estoy usando el apin de CoinMarketCap y esta es la estructura de datos:

```
{
  "data": {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Bitcoin",
      "symbol": "BTC",
      "website_slug": "bitcoin",
      "rank": 1,
      "circulating_supply": 17168112.0,
      "total_supply": 17168112.0,
      "max_supply": 21000000.0,
      "quotes": {
        "USD": {
          "price": 8159.91,
          "volume_24h": 6805930000.0,
          "market_cap": 140090248790.0,
          "percent_change_1h": -0.65,
          "percent_change_24h": 5.84,
          "percent_change_7d": 18.14
        }
      },
      "last_updated": 1532445803
    },
    "1027": {
      "id": 1027,
      "name": "Ethereum",
      "symbol": "ETH",
      "website_slug": "ethereum",
      "rank": 2,
      "circulating_supply": 100891486.0,
      "total_supply": 100891486.0,
      "max_supply": null,
      "quotes": {
        "USD": {
          "price": 472.418,
          "volume_24h": 2187530000.0,
          "market_cap": 47662953974.0,
          "percent_change_1h": -1.42,
          "percent_change_24h": 2.14,
          "percent_change_7d": -1.83
        }
      },
      "last_updated": 1532445813
    },
    "52": {
      "id": 52,
      "name": "XRP",
      "symbol": "XRP",
      "website_slug": "ripple",
      "rank": 3,
      "circulating_supply": 39315683476.0,
      "total_supply": 99991900487.0,
      "max_supply": 100000000000.0,
      "quotes": {
        "USD": {
          "price": 0.458599,
          "volume_24h": 305718000.0,
          "market_cap": 18030133126.0,
          "percent_change_1h": -1.22,
          "percent_change_24h": 1.69,
          "percent_change_7d": -5.25
        }
      },
      "last_updated": 1532445797
    },
  "metadata": {
    "timestamp": 1532445415,
    "num_cryptocurrencies": 1664,
    "error": null
  }
}
```

Como puede ver son diccionarios anidados y llega un punto en el que no puede iterar explícitamente, debemos hacerlo de forma dinámica, de lo contrario deberíamos conocer la identificación de la moneda de cifrado.

Comenzamos la exploración de los diccionarios:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import json
import requests

response = requests.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/")
data = json.loads(response.text)


def keep(data):
    for i in data['data'].key():
        print(i)


keep(data)
```

Como puede ver, esta es la parte compleja para iterar.

Logré deshacerme de la parte compleja para obtener el Top10 de cryptocurrencies:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import json
import requests

response = requests.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/")
data = json.loads(response.text)


def keep(data):
    for i in data['data'].values():
        if i['rank'] <= 10:
            print(json.dumps(i, indent=4))


keep(data)
```

Pero no puedo escribirlo en un archivo JSON, espero que pueda ayudarme, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Nelson no se si ha sido un error con el sitio en ingles, dado que tienes cuenta en ambos pero has publicado en [es.so] si la traduces para que se adapte a las normas del sitio te podremos ayudar. Un saludo.

Comment: @FJSevilla gracias, ya edite la publicacion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para crear tu fichero JSON con el "Top10" solo tienes que filtrar como haces pero en vez de intentar serializar cada item por separado, agrégalo a una lista o diccionario, que luego serializas con `jsom.dump`(para crear un fichero .json) o con `json.dumps` para crear una cadena representando uno:

```
top_10 = [i for i in data['data'].values() if i['rank'] <= 10]
with open('top10.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(top_10, fp, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

Con lo que obtienes un fichero con la siguiente estructura:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bitcoin",
        "symbol": "BTC",
        "website_slug": "bitcoin",
        "rank": 1,
        "circulating_supply": 17168400.0,
        "total_supply": 17168400.0,
        "max_supply": 21000000.0,
        "quotes": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 8231.71,
                "volume_24h": 6899640000.0,
                "market_cap": 141325289964.0,
                "percent_change_1h": 0.68,
                "percent_change_24h": 6.51,
                "percent_change_7d": 17.23
            }
        },
        "last_updated": 1532453664
    },
    {
        "id": 1027,
        "name": "Ethereum",
        "symbol": "ETH",
        "website_slug": "ethereum",
        "rank": 2,
        "circulating_supply": 100893214.0,
        "total_supply": 100893214.0,
        "max_supply": null,
        "quotes": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 475.778,
                "volume_24h": 2195980000.0,
                "market_cap": 48002771511.0,
                "percent_change_1h": 0.55,
                "percent_change_24h": 3.94,
                "percent_change_7d": -2.2
            }
        },
        "last_updated": 1532453675
    },

    ....
]
```

Ahora bien si quieres mantener la estructura del JSON original puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
top_10 = {"data": {k: v for k, v in data['data'].items() if v['rank'] <= 10}}
with open('top10.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(top_10, fp)
```

Con lo que obtienes un fichero como el siguiente:

```
{
    "data": {
        "1": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Bitcoin",
            "symbol": "BTC",
            "website_slug": "bitcoin",
            "rank": 1,
            "circulating_supply": 17168400.0,
            "total_supply": 17168400.0,
            "max_supply": 21000000.0,
            "quotes": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 8214.46,
                    "volume_24h": 6881340000.0,
                    "market_cap": 141029135064.0,
                    "percent_change_1h": 0.46,
                    "percent_change_24h": 6.3,
                    "percent_change_7d": 17.05
                }
            },
            "last_updated": 1532453368
        },
        "1027": {
            "id": 1027,
            "name": "Ethereum",
            "symbol": "ETH",
            "website_slug": "ethereum",
            "rank": 2,
            "circulating_supply": 100893214.0,
            "total_supply": 100893214.0,
            "max_supply": null,
            "quotes": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 474.556,
                    "volume_24h": 2187020000.0,
                    "market_cap": 47879480003.0,
                    "percent_change_1h": 0.22,
                    "percent_change_24h": 3.63,
                    "percent_change_7d": -2.42
                }
            },
            "last_updated": 1532453376
        },
        "52": {
            "id": 52,
            "name": "XRP",
            "symbol": "XRP",
            "website_slug": "ripple",
            "rank": 3,
            "circulating_supply": 39315683476.0,
            "total_supply": 99991900487.0,
            "max_supply": 100000000000.0,
            "quotes": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 0.456089,
                    "volume_24h": 308807000.0,
                    "market_cap": 17931450761.0,
                    "percent_change_1h": -0.14,
                    "percent_change_24h": 1.9,
                    "percent_change_7d": -7.08
                }
            },
            "last_updated": 1532453356
        },
        "1831": {
            "id": 1831,
            "name": "Bitcoin Cash",
            "symbol": "BCH",
            "website_slug": "bitcoin-cash",
            "rank": 4,
            "circulating_supply": 17254788.0,
            "total_supply": 17254788.0,
            "max_supply": 21000000.0,
            "quotes": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 855.979,
                    "volume_24h": 861947000.0,
                    "market_cap": 14769735749.0,
                    "percent_change_1h": 0.67,
                    "percent_change_24h": 7.56,
                    "percent_change_7d": 4.28
                }
            },
            "last_updated": 1532453376
        },
        "1765": {
            "id": 1765,
            "name": "EOS",
            "symbol": "EOS",
            "website_slug": "eos",
            "rank": 5,
            "circulating_supply": 896149492.0,
            "total_supply": 900000000.0,
            "max_supply": 1000000000.0,
            "quotes": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 8.48947,
                    "volume_24h": 966135000.0,
                    "market_cap": 7607834229.0,
                    "percent_change_1h": 1.27,
                    "percent_change_24h": 6.67,
                    "percent_change_7d": 1.49
                }
            },
            "last_updated": 1532453377
        },
        "512": {
            "id": 512,
            "name": "Stellar",
            "symbol": "XLM",
            "website_slug": "stellar",
            "rank": 6,
            "circulating_supply": 18767299129.0,
            "total_supply": 104144920420.0,
            "max_supply": null,
            "quotes": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 0.300038,
                    "volume_24h": 106479000.0,
                    "market_cap": 5630902896.0,
                    "percent_change_1h": -0.03,
                    "percent_change_24h": 5.2,
                    "percent_change_7d": 24.63
                }
            },
            "last_updated": 1532453365
        },
        "2": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Litecoin",
            "symbol": "LTC",
            "website_slug": "litecoin",
            "rank": 7,
            "circulating_supply": 57548957.0,
            "total_supply": 57548957.0,
            "max_supply": 84000000.0,
            "quotes": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 87.8045,
                    "volume_24h": 411849000.0,
                    "market_cap": 5053057399.0,
                    "percent_change_1h": 0.54,
                    "percent_change_24h": 4.48,
                    "percent_change_7d": 1.57
                }
            },
            "last_updated": 1532453350
        },
        "2010": {
            "id": 2010,
            "name": "Cardano",
            "symbol": "ADA",
            "website_slug": "cardano",
            "rank": 8,
            "circulating_supply": 25927070538.0,
            "total_supply": 31112483745.0,
            "max_supply": 45000000000.0,
            "quotes": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 0.17286,
                    "volume_24h": 191886000.0,
                    "market_cap": 4481753413.0,
                    "percent_change_1h": -0.03,
                    "percent_change_24h": 2.89,
                    "percent_change_7d": 7.56
                }
            },
            "last_updated": 1532453378
        },
        "1720": {
            "id": 1720,
            "name": "IOTA",
            "symbol": "MIOTA",
            "website_slug": "iota",
            "rank": 9,
            "circulating_supply": 2779530283.0,
            "total_supply": 2779530283.0,
            "max_supply": 2779530283.0,
            "quotes": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 0.979802,
                    "volume_24h": 46447800.0,
                    "market_cap": 2723389330.0,
                    "percent_change_1h": 0.61,
                    "percent_change_24h": 1.93,
                    "percent_change_7d": -11.04
                }
            },
            "last_updated": 1532453372
        },
        "825": {
            "id": 825,
            "name": "Tether",
            "symbol": "USDT",
            "website_slug": "tether",
            "rank": 10,
            "circulating_supply": 2507140346.0,
            "total_supply": 3080109502.0,
            "max_supply": null,
            "quotes": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 0.996441,
                    "volume_24h": 4194340000.0,
                    "market_cap": 2498217433.0,
                    "percent_change_1h": -0.15,
                    "percent_change_24h": -0.19,
                    "percent_change_7d": -0.48
                }
            },
            "last_updated": 1532453373
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: antes que nada gracias por tu respuesta, por otro lado quisiera consultar  lo siguiente:

la primera opcion tambien es una es una sintaxis de dicts comprehension?

por otro lado ¿Es mas eficiente dicts comprehension que el bucle for?

si quisieras por ejemplo agregar un poco de complejidad al asunto y obtener ahora un top10 de cripto monedas pero que cumplan con cierto regla de precios, es un ejemplo que se me acaba de ocurrir para ilustrar por ejemplo procesar estos datos y agregar alguna regla que pueda evaluar si tienes el dinero para invertir segun algun criterio.

Comment: La primera opción es "lists comprehension" en realidad ya que estamos creando una lista (que contine diccionarios, pero una lista), en la segunda se usa "dicts comprehensions" en `{k: v for k, v in data['data'].items() if v['rank'] <= 10}`. en cuanto a la eficiencia, si es más eficiente por norma general, aunque también menos legible (debes valorar si te merece o no la pena).  A grandes rasgos se debe a que se evita la sobrecarga de la llamada a la función  `list.append` manteniendo la creación de la lista a nivel de C ya que se usa un un bytecode especializado(`LIST_APPEND`).

Comment: En cuanto a lo de añadir complejidad, pues ya depende del caso concreto podrás o no usar list-comprehensions, si quieres filtrar aquellos que están en el top 10 y que además `"price"` está entre 1 y 500 incluidos puedes hacer `top_10 = [i for i in data['data'].values()
              if i['rank'] <= 10 and 1 <= i["quotes"]["USD"]["price"] <= 500 ]`